# what will happen if we have more statements in coding after function return code?

Tags: php

I have basic question for you guys

i have php function which verifies and creates the file handler name for the given type,

however i just want to know if the following code goes to a else, will the next lines of the coding of creating the guid will be executed or will it be ignored ?

```
private function fileFormat($type=false){

    if($type=='CreditCard')
        $prefix='CC-';
    elseif($type=='DirectDebit')
        $prefix='DD-';
    else 
        return false;   

    $date         = $prefix.'-'.date('d-m-Y', time());
    $guid         = '' . md5($date) . '.csv';
    return $guid;   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to beat a dead horse, now that there are a number of answers stating the same thing... but here is my clarification.

After a `return` is **executed**, no remaining code will be executed.  The way you have setup your code is fine, assuming you want a `false` returned if neither of the `$type`s are encountered.  This is a common control flow and is preferred over setting a flag and checking the flaw before return.

```
if ($myCondition_1) {
    $a = 1;
} elseif ($myCondition_2) {
    $a = 2;
} else {
    return False;
}
other_operation_on_a($a);
return $a;
```

Is preferred (for me) over:

```
$a = False;
if ($myCondition_1) {
    $a = 1;
} elseif ($myCondition_2) {
    $a = 2;
} 
if ($a !== False) {
    other_operation_on_a($a);
}
return $a;
```

Answer (score 2):

They will be ignored. Anything after `return` statement will not be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever the `return false` is executed the following lines will not be executed. However you must make sure at the spot you call your function you can 100% distinguish between the return values from `return false` and a `return $guid`

Answer (score 2):

No more lines execute after a return statement is executed.

Answer (score 2):

Simply it will not execute (*ignore*) the lines following `return`.

Answer (score 1):

The function will return and everything after the encountered return statement will not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that control is returned to the calling method.... So those lines will never execute. 
For example if your IDE is good, you are given warnings in the case of redundant statements after the return e.g:

```
function PrintHelloWorld()
{
   if($userPresent)
   {
     echo "Hello World" ;
   }
   return "World empty!";
   $something = "blah" ; //redundant (will never execute)
   $something+="Blah" ; //redundant (will never execute) 
//A good IDE should give warnings. But you usually see them as grayed out
}
```

Comment: OP's return statement is in an `else`. Therefore the IDE will not give a warning. If the else is not hit, the code will be executed normally.

Comment: @barts  I know, I was giving an example that should make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

They'll be ignored because the return will be executed by the else (default) case.